# xbacklight No outputs have backlight property

Tags: xorg, backlight, xbacklight

When I try running `xbacklight -inc 10` I get an error message "No outputs have backlight property"

I've searched the issue and found several answers usually suggesting some form of modifying `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` which I have previously done on this laptop to get backlight working in the first place

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics" 
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

the unique thing about my situation this time around, is xbacklight was working fine until after I installed the intel graphics drivers through the oibaf PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

after running the above commands and rebooting I found my mouse and keyboard didn't work so I had to reinstall the drivers by running

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

after all this the game I was trying to play still didn't work so I removed the PPA and uninstalled `xserver-xorg-input-all`

I couldn't scroll with my Touchpad after this as well so I had to reinstall that package as well(`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`).

This is why I suspect the xbacklight issue isn't a problem with the config, but instead when I was removing the drivers I removed xbacklight drivers. Is there another package I need to install to restore xbacklight?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Since a few versions, Ubuntu defaults to using the kernel mode drivers for Intel graphics cards. You may want to add specifics on your system version and your graphics card by including the output of `lshw -class display` and `lsb_release -a`